# uicollectionview navigationcontroller didselectitematindexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make a navigation-site for my app with an UICollectionView. As a user clicks on one of the cells, the ViewController should push another one with a zooming animation of the Image of the cell.

Everything is working fine and the next view is shown but here is the problem: when I called the next view and then navigate back to my UICollectionView and click on my cell again, the animation isn't shown anymore. 
So I think that the ViewController doesn't call the 
`-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}`
function anymore and kind of remembers the seque. But how do I tell him to do the animation again?

Here is the code for the segue:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CostumCollectionCell *theCell =(CostumCollectionCell*)[self.theCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *overlayer = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:theCell.theImageView.image];
    overlayer.frame=theCell.frame;
    [overlayer setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [self.theCollectionView addSubview:overlayer];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
        overlayer.frame=CGRectMake(theCell.frame.origin.x-theCell.frame.size.width/2, theCell.frame.origin.y-theCell.frame.size.height/2, theCell.frame.size.width*2, theCell.frame.size.height*2);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"auditionView"] animated:YES];
                [overlayer removeFromSuperview];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];

}
```

**updated code:**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CostumCollectionCell *theCell =(CostumCollectionCell*)[self.theCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.overlayer setImage:theCell.theImageView.image];
    self.overlayer.frame=theCell.frame;
    [self.overlayer setHidden:NO];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.overlayer.frame=CGRectMake(theCell.frame.origin.x-theCell.frame.size.width/2, theCell.frame.origin.y-theCell.frame.size.height/2, theCell.frame.size.width*2, theCell.frame.size.height*2);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"auditionSegue" sender:self];
                [self.overlayer setHidden:YES];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }];


}
```

Comment: You don't have to 'think' - you can set a breakpoint in this method and know, but unless you have removed the delegate it seems unlikely.  As a matter of style you should look at spring animations - they are the 'new' style and perhaps use `performSegueWithIdentifier` rather than pushing the new view controller directly

Comment: Okay I did some changes according to your answer. I don't THINK i KNOW now that he calls the method but just doesn't show the animation.
edit:
seems like he gets nil for the cell in the second call o.O

Comment: Did you check that `theCell` is not nil?

Comment: Okay found the solution: I accidentally released the cell in the next step because i shuffled the images.It works now. Thanks for your help guys! And these spring animations rock ;)